# Save as file without prompt for file name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a PDF file without any user interface, other than clicking a button within the Excel file.

Using the below code, when the file is to be saved as with an automatically generated name, the code prompts for the filename, instead of grabbing it from the code.

I have a feeling that `sendkeys` is not working out.

```
Sub PrinttoPDFTest()

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$F$17"
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$F$17"
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
    End With

    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="Adobe PDF on Ne04:", Collate:=True

    newHour = Hour(Now())
    newMinute = Minute(Now())
    newSecond = Second(Now()) + 5
    waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
    Application.Wait waitTime

    Filename = "C:\Temp\PDF\" & ActiveSheet.Range("DateSerial").Value & ".pdf"

    SendKeys Filename & "{Enter}", False

End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look here: [ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=25773)

Comment: Okay, posted as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It would be simpler to use .ExportAsFixedFormat rather than .PrintOut, and just stack your requests (no delay code needed):

```
Sub ExporttoPDF()

    Sheets("Sheet1").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "C:\Folder\Filename1.pdf"
    Sheets("Sheet2").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "C:\Folder\Filename2.pdf"

End Sub
```

Just replace the destinations and filenames, and this code should work fine.  If you want to use a value in the sheet as part of a filename, then you can concatenate (&) like this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "C:\Folder\" & Range("P10").Value & ".pdf"
```

Or store the filename in a variable and do it this way:

```
dim filename as string

filename = Range("P10").Value

Sheets("Sheet1").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, filename
```

And it goes on and on...

Comment: Thank you for this Rob, I was just testing your code and I am getting: Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. What is the name of the Reference I need to use? thx

Comment: Agreed that the ExportAsFixedFormat allows you to avoid the last step that you need when printing to PDF. However the export PDF is four times the size as the one created by printing. when I print to pdf I get a file size of 22kp when I save as pdf I get 84. sice we attache alot of PDF's to emails the difference can cause the email to be to big to send.